# Domínio. com Website Rstudio

Tags: r, web-service, shiny

tudo bem?

Vcs poderiam me dar um auxilio? Eu quero garantir um dominio .com para construir meu site com shiny/markdown.

Mas ainda estou estudando shiny/html/css portanto ainda vou produzir meu site.

Nesa situacao como faço para garantir meu dominio .com?

Conheco pouco dessa parte da web.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Existe alguns serviços na internet para você fazer o seu registro prévio. 
Uol host é uma empresa de sp que faz esse registro no Brasil e você consegue gerar um boleto e pagar o seu domínio. Porém nós da Aranha Agency preferimos utilizar o serviço namecheap. (é um otimo servioço para registro, porém você vai precisar de um cartão internacional.)

- Registro Br - somante registra dominios [.com.br] ex: meusite.com.br
- UolHost - Registro de dominios no Brasil.
- Namecheap - Registro de dominios no mundo.

Espero ter ajudado.